# embed chat - problem with triggering script

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a script that loads an external chat:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   const token = document.querySelector('script[token]').getAttribute('token');
});
```

My page is SPA, and the token is dependent on user information.

To my understanding, `DOMContentLoaded` event triggers only once and before the user logs in, so there is no way of generating a token for the script, and generating it after login didn't work because the script couldn't get executed.

Is there any way to go around this, and trigger DOM event manually?

Comment: why can't the script execute after the user logs in?

Comment: @Kokodoko becouse it triggers on DOMContentLoaded and my website is SPA so the event triggered already when login form appeared. After user logs in DOMContentLoaded  doesnt trigger

Comment: Yes, but why can't you change that? You can trigger your own function after the user logs in?

Comment: @Kokodoko i can only add tag to my code <script src="..." data-em-token="..."> </script>that loads the script, it is from exteranl provider so i cannot change it

Comment: If you have no control over the HTML page, that script will always execute after the DOM content has loaded, before the user does anything.

Comment: `data-em-token="..."` is not going to be picked up by `document.querySelector('script[token]').getAttribute('token');` - you would need `document.querySelector('script[data-em-token]').getAttribute('data-em-token');`